# java sqlite - Error: function not yet implemented for SQLite

Tags: java, jdbc

I created the following class in java to make using SQLite easier when I code.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Dbm {
//We want to use the connection througout the whole class so it is
//provided as a class level private variable
private Connection c = null;
//This constructor openes or creates the database provided by the arguement
//NameOfDatabase
public Dbm(String NameOfDatabase){

try {
  //Database is checked for in project folder, if doesnt exist then creates database
  c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + NameOfDatabase);
} catch ( Exception e ) {
  System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
  System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
}
public void CloseDB(){
try{
c.close();
System.out.println("Closed Database Successfull");
}
catch (Exception e){
System.out.println("Failed to close Database due to error: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
 public void ExecuteNoReturnQuery(String SqlCommand){
//creates a statment to execute the query
try{
    Statement stmt = null;
stmt = c.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(SqlCommand);
stmt.close();
System.out.println("Sql query executed successfull");
} catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println("Failed to execute query due to error: " +     e.getMessage());
}
}
// this method returns a ResultSet for a query which can be iterated throughd
public ResultSet ExecuteSqlQueryWithReturn(String SqlCommand){
try{

Statement stmt = null;


stmt = c.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SqlCommand);
 return rs;
}catch (Exception e){
System.out.println("An Error has ocured while executing this query" + e.getMessage());
}
return null;
}
}
```

Here is the main code in the program

```
import java.sql.*;

public class InstaText {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Dbm db = new Dbm("people.db");
 ResultSet rs = db.ExecuteSqlQueryWithReturn("select * from people;");
try{
   String name = "";
   int age = 0;
   String address = "";
 while (rs.isLast() == false){
 name = rs.getString("name");
 age = rs.getInt("age");
 address = rs.getString("address");
         System.out.println("Name is " + name +" age is " + age + " Address is " + address);
         rs.next();
 }
}catch (Exception e ){
System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
      db.CloseDB();
   }
 }
```

But when I execute it I get the following output:

```
 Opened database successfully
 Error: function not yet implemented for SQLite
 Closed Database Successfull
```

So how do I solve the Error "Error: function not yet implemented for SQLite"?
I am running the NetBeans Ide with the latest JDBC on mac os sierra.

Edit: Here is the output after adding e.printstacktrace(); in the catch block:

```
Opened database successfully
Error: function not yet implemented for SQLite
java.sql.SQLException: function not yet implemented for SQLite
Closed Database Successfull
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.isLast(JDBC3ResultSet.java:155)
at instatext.InstaText.main(InstaText.java:24)
```

Comment: You use a function not implemented in your code. You should find another way to do what you do. Can you add the stracktrace in your question ?

Comment: how do I get the stacktrace? I am using the Netbeans Ide

Comment: Fast answer : you may do  `e.printStackTrace()` in your `catch` block. A logger is better.

Comment: I added the stack trace to the question

Comment: Is their any other way to retrieve the whole table in a ResultSet object other then (select * from people;)?

Comment: No, don't change your query. The problem is the way you use to retrieve its result. I have just done you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not your select query but the `isLast()` method you are using on the `ResultSet` instance to retrieve the result.
 Try the `next()` method, it should work :

```
while (rs.next()){
 name = rs.getString("name");
 age = rs.getInt("age");
 address = rs.getString("address");
         System.out.println("Name is " + name +" age is " + age + " Address is " + address);
         rs.next();
 }
```

You can read here :
https://github.com/bonitasoft/bonita-connector-database/issues/1
that with SQLLite, you may have some limitations with the `isLast()` method :

> According to JDBC documentation
>   (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)
>   calls to isLast() and first() methods are forbidden if the result set
>   type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY (e.g SQLite).